# Intellij Spring Initializr not available

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-initializr

I'm using Intellij IDE to code spring Boot.

Spring Initializr was not available for me in the `new project` option as in.

http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2015/03/develop-spring-boot-applications-more-productively-with-intellij-idea-14-1/

Below you can find the screenshot of my IDE. Please let me know what am i missing here?

[image]

Comment: Use this link:- https://wiki.openmrs.org/display/docs/Use+Maven+In+Intellij+IDEA

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Please verify "Spring Boot" plugin is enabled.

In File > Settings > Plugins, you will probably find the Plugin unselected:

[image: Spring Boot Plugin still unselected]

(The above a screenshot of *Intellij IDEA 2018.1 Ultimate*)

Comment: Would be nice to mention this in the documentation ( https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring.html#spring-boot )

Comment: Btw you need to enable `Spring Boot` AND `Spring MVC`.

Comment: No, we can use Spring Assistant plugin in IDEA CE, to do the same.

Comment: is it a paid version? i tried but its asking to provide the lisence.

Answer (score 177):

Although the asker here used IntelliJ Ultimate here, I'd like to point out that the Spring Initializer is only available in the ultimate edition, not in the community edition. If you are using the community version, there is no way to enable the Spring plugin here.

Comment: So how do you start a spring boot project?

Comment: @shinzou I think the only way to do it is either command line or https://start.spring.io/ (see Chris' answer).

Comment: No, we can use Spring Assistant plugin in IDEA CE, to do the same.

Comment: have installed community. now downloaded ultimate. thanks

Comment: Thanks for that, I did not knew it and was looking for the plugin for a while

Answer (score 85):

If you only have IntelliJ IDEA CE then you can still create Spring Boot applications. First generate your project directory  using https://start.spring.io and then import into IntelliJ IDEA and off you go.

Comment: The missing step: Unzip the downloaded project somewhere, then import from the "build.gradle" file (presume this works fine with pom.xml as well)

Comment: No, just check we have Spring Assistant for IDEA CE now

Comment: There is no run configuration set to run the project generated from start.spring.io. Not able to find an example for that too. Could you point to helpful resource?

Answer (score 69):

I know this post is old, but this might help someone.

**Spring Assistant** is a plugin available for IntelliJ IDEA CE which has a spring framework integration for creating Spring Boot Projects.

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10229-spring-assistant

Here is how it looks in IDEA IntelliJ editor

[image]

Comment: Appears to be a reimplementation/clone.  Seems to get the job done.

Comment: Thanks. It helped me. I was starting to think that only the Ultimate Edition had Spring support and that I'd have to only rely on the Spring Initializr website.

Comment: Unfortunately, the plugin that served part of the idea/spring community, stopped maintaining. I took the liberty of creating a fork, we fixed bugs and added new features.
the same can be found directly in the search for Intellij or in the marketplace.
[Spring Initializr and Assistant](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18622-spring-initializr-and-assistant)

Answer (score 8):

Now Intilij Community edition is supporting the spring initilizer by plugin Spring Assistant.
Install Spring Assistant in plugin section. This plugin will help you to call spring initializer for project creation.

[image]

to Install Spring Assistant  go to plugin and search Spring select "Spring Assistant"
[image]

Comment: plugin banned in idea CE

Comment: Unfortunately, the plugin that served part of the idea/spring community, stopped maintaining. I took the liberty of creating a fork, we fixed bugs and added new features.

the same can be found directly in the search for Intellij or in the marketplace.
[spring-initializr-and-assistant](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18622-spring-initializr-and-assistant)

Answer (score 4):

For Mac OS - Intellij -
Refer below Navigation to add Plugins :

Intelij IDEA>>Preference>>Plugins>>Search Spring & install Spring tool & Assistance

Answer (score 2):

Adding screenshot from latest 2019.2 IDEA Ultimate Edition:

- Go to `File -> Settings -> Plugins`
- search for `spring boot` under `Installed` plugins list
- Press the `Enable` button
- Restart IDE

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to File -> Setting -> Plugins ->
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGYpE.png
Here Displaying MarketPlace And Installed, -> click on installed search for spring assistant
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF4xd.png
click on checkbox and click on ok-> intellij automatically ask restart the ide. Click on restart. After this spring assistant display while creating spring boot application

Answer (score 1):

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 CE and I don't see Spring or Spring Boot options in plugin. Spring Assistant plugin is available but it's not fully featured like native plugins.

- For example application.properties auto completion will not work. There is no styling. All is grayed out.
- In Facets, there is no option to choose Spring to mark it Spring Boot.

I download spring boot project from start.spring.io and use it in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 CE with limited features. I think all nice to have features of Spring/Spring Boot are now only part of IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate edition. See [comparison](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

Spring Assistant plugin can help to generate new app as a start without leaving IntelliJ IDEA CE which is good.

Answer (score 1):

In intellij idea navigate to the File-> Settings. In the Plugins section search for **Spring Assistant**. Then install the Spring Assistant plugin.
[image]

Then restart the intellij idea and create the spring boot application.

Answer (score 1):

As of **April 2022**, the name of plugin is **Spring Initializr and Assistant** (works for IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1 Community Edition).

**UPDATE**: Starting 2022.4.3 , its been renamed to Spring Boot Helper and needs you to buy license (see the image attached).
[image]

Comment: any idea about 2022.3.2 release?

Comment: @Suresh I think its changed in the recent versions - currently requires you to buy license. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Settings > Plugin > Spring Boot helper

Install this plugin and use it for 1 month trail.(This seems to be the
working option as I tried)

[Plugin - Spring Boot Helper]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65JuB.png)

Comment: This gives an impression of "buy and use this commercial thing" and might not be perceived as a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late entry, but I'm hoping it might help somebody.  I have IntelliJ Ultimate and had all of the Spring plugins enabled after installing the application.  When I tried to create a Spring Boot project, Spring Initializer was not in my list of options just like the OP's problem.

I didn't find a solution here so I went to `File -> Settings -> Plugins` and tried disabling my Spring Boot plugin and restarting.  Then I re-enabled Spring Boot and restarted and voila I now have the Spring Initializer available in the New Project Wizard.

Answer (score 0):

January 2023, in the 2022.3.1 version of **Intelijj idea, spring assistant continues to work** (it has a certain bug in the interface). At least in what I'm testing, it creates the project and correctly installs the dependencies that I indicate

This is the repository of the latest version they released on git:

https://github.com/cheng6563/intellij-spring-assistant.git

This is the link to the page:

https://github.com/cheng6563/intellij-spring-assistant

The version of this **Spring Assistant is v1.0.6**

https://github.com/cheng6563/intellij-spring-assistant/releases

I hope my comment works for someone (sorry for any grammatical errors or wrong words; I'm using google translate to help people who need what I do)

Answer (score -1):

Though the user asked about the ultimate version its good to know that community version provides a plugin called  Spring Assistant plugin which guides to a spring boot project.

File-> Settings -> Spring Assistant

 Then restart the IDE Then,
File-> New -> Project -> Spring Assistant

Comment: spring assistant will help to suggest annotations in code

Answer (score -1):

If you don't see the spring plugins available in the list, make sure to click on marketplace at the top center. By default, you see the installed plugins only.

Comment: This answer is of no use to anyone. Don't give generalized statements.

Comment: @Suresh I made this mistake myself, searching for a plugin in this page. The button I am mentioning is not visible at first sight and noone mentioned this before.

Answer (score -2):

In Intellij Go To

File > Settings > Plugins,

Search "Spring" And Check All plugin Started With Spring Then Restart intellij